# Jquery.cascade plugin how to match text instead of value?

Tags: jquery, plugins, cascade

I am using plugin from [here](http://devlicio.us/blogs/mike_nichols/archive/2008/05/25/jquery-cascade-cascading-values-from-forms.aspx). Thanks for it.

I use it for multiple dropdowns. The thing is I want it to filter source list based on text, however plugin filters only by value. Believe it is set in this line:

`.filter(function() { return opt.match.call(this, opt.getParentValue(parent)); })`

- opt.match.call - calls match method on dropdown
- this - it is list to be filtered
- opt.getParentValue(parent) - returns id of selected value, this I wanna change.

I just dont know how should I change the plugin itself to provide selectedItem or directly the text.

Any idea is appreciated. Thanks in advance. Cheers, X.

**Edit:**
Finaly I've found the solution. I needed to modified the jquery.cascade.js like this:

`getParentValue: function(parent) { return $(parent+" option:selected"); }`

and then I could get to the text value. :-) So my match criterium looks like this:

`function matchStates(selectedItem) {

    return this.When == selectedItem.val() && this.Where == selectedItem.text();

};`

Answer (score 1):

You want to define a function yourself and pass it in the options when you setup your cascade.

```
    jQuery("#your_child").cascade("#parent_control", {
        getParentValue: function(parent) {
            // write code to return the text of
            // #parent_control instead of the value here
        }
    });
```